# Rpackage: Rstudio possibly generating bad NAMESPACE file

Tags: r, namespaces, rcpp

I am making an R package in Rstudio and I selected the option `Configure Build Tools > Configure` and select `Use roxygen to generate NAMESPACE`. I wrote my functions in Rcpp and this is what the `NAMESPACE` looks like when I generate it with `roxygen2`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand

export(function1)
export(function2)
export(function3)
export(function4)
```

Since my functions are written with Rcpp, which I then export, then they will used in R via `.Call`. However, from [writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) we should use `useDynLib()` in such a case. This is why I think I am getting an error when I try to call `function1` and the error is:

```
Error in .Call("Mypackage_function1", PACKAGE = "Mypackage", var1,  : 
"Mypackage_function1" not available for .Call() for package "Mypackage"
```

When I use the default `NAMESPACE` when I start a project in Rstudio, I have the following in `NAMESPACE`:

```
useDynLib(packagename)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
```

When I use the default `NAMESPACE` I can call the functions using `.Call` however I get a warning when I check the package that I am not generating the `NAMESPACE` using roxygen.

Is there a fix for this? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to the usage of RStudio: For Roxygen to generate the relevant `useDynLib` specification, [you need to use the `@useDynLib` tag in a Roxygen doc comment](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html):

```
#' @useDynLib packagename
```

You can do this anywhere (where you can use normal Roxygen comments) but it makes sense to put this into the package documentation, rather than the documentation of a specific function. Usually this resides in a file called `R/packagename-package.r`:

```
#' My package documentation
#' … bla bla …
#' @name packagename
#' @docType package
#' @useDynLib packagename
NULL
```